# French dependency parser outputs lots of MWE?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am giving the following input to the dep. parser,

```
Dickinson quitte Iron Maiden en 1993, remplacé par Blaze Bayley, pour
commencer une carrière solo qui le voit expérimenter de larges
variétés et styles de heavy metal et de rock.
```

The output parse in conll is does not contain many dependency relations.
Almost everything is mwe.

Following is the output.

```
1   Dickinson   _   NC  _   0   ROOT
2   quitte  _   ADJ _   3   amod
3   Iron    _   NPP _   1   compound
4   Maiden  _   NPP _   3   compound
5   en  _   P   _   4   mwe
6   1993    _   N   _   5   mwe
7   ,   _   PUNC    _   6   compound
8   remplacé    _   VPP _   7   appos
9   par _   P   _   8   case
10  Blaze   _   NPP _   9   case
11  Bayley  _   NPP _   10  mwe
12  ,   _   PUNC    _   11  compound
13  pour    _   P   _   12  compound
14  commencer   _   VINF    _   13  mwe
15  une _   DET _   16  det
16  carrière    _   NC  _   14  nmod
17  solo    _   ADJ _   16  amod
18  qui _   PROREL  _   20  nsubj
19  le  _   CLO _   20  det
20  voit    _   V   _   17  acl:relcl
21  expérimenter    _   VINF    _   20  compound
22  de  _   P   _   21  compound
23  larges  _   ADJ _   24  amod
24  variétés    _   NC  _   22  appos
25  et  _   CC  _   24  cc
26  styles  _   NC  _   25  mwe
27  de  _   P   _   28  case
28  heavy   _   ET  _   26  nmod
29  metal   _   ET  _   28  compound
30  et  _   CC  _   29  compound
31  de  _   P   _   32  case
32  rock    _   NC  _   30  nmod
33  .   _   PUNC    _   1   dep
```

Answer (score 0):

This is our first attempt at a French dependency parser, so it will definitely have some issues.  Please let us know if you see any patterns in the errors it makes so we can know what areas to focus on for improving the model.

One thing though, I am unclear why you say almost everything is mwe, I count 28 non-mwe relations and 5 mwe relations in your example.

Comment: I am trying to extract (subj,rel,obj) triples from the parse, but seems like the labels are quite different. Any help will be appreciated!